# The right format of an object for a v-for

Tags: vue.js, object, vuejs2, v-for

I would like to display each answer that have been shuffle in `melange()` but `reponse` return anything. I don't know what's wrong with my v-for. May be the format of my object.

```
             <label v-bind:key="key" class="bg-white block mt-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg py-2 px-6 text-lg"
                v-for="reponse,key in reponseQuestion(questions[currentQuestion].idQuestion)" 
                <div class="fas fa-check" v-bind:id="key" 
                v-bind:value="reponse" 
                v-on:click="repondu(key)"
                v-bind:disabled="questionSelectionne != ''">
                    {{ reponse }}
                </div>
            </label>


        reponseQuestion(idQuest) {
            this.$axios
                .get("http://localhost:4000/api/answers/" + idQuest)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(this.melange(response.data[0]))
                    return this.melange(response.data[0])
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },
        melange(obj) {
            // new obj to return
            let newObj = {};
            // create keys array
            var keys = Object.keys(obj);
            // randomize keys array
            keys.sort(function () {
                return Math.random() - 0.5;
            });
            // save in new array
            keys.forEach(function (k) {
                newObj[k] = obj[k];
            });
            return newObj
        }
```

Result of reponseQuestion() :

```
{reponse4: "8 s 36", reponse3: "8 s 42", reponse2: "9 s 72", reponse1: "9 s 58"}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need braces around `(response,key) in responseQuestion` to override the operator precedence.

Comment: I add braces around responseQuestion `return {newObj}` and i change the v-for `reponse,key in reponseQuestion(questions[questionActuel].idQuestion)[newObj]` that's what you mean ?

Comment: I mean that without braces, the comma operator between `response` and `key`  has a higher precedence than the `in` keyword.